# Unable to send FCM notification to device using NodeJS Admin SDK

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am following the code mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/server-integration/#send-messages-to-topics) to send a notification through Admin SDK.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const message = {
    data: {
      type: "warning",
      content: "A new weather warning has been created!",
    },
    topic: "weather",
  };
  
  admin
    .messaging()
    .send(message)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
    res.end();
});
```

After running the above code using Firebase emulator, the console prints

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-sendNotification"
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-sendNotification" in ~1s
>  Successfully sent message: projects/foo/messages/2216986345254434321
```

However, I don't see any notification on the device.

**NOTE**: If I send the notification through Firebase Notification composer or Postman to the same topic `weather`, the device does show a notification. I don't know what's wrong in the code above.

Comment: can you please share your client side code also , I am facing same issue. Do we need to register any token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) which requires you to handle the display yourself.

Checkout [Message Types](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#message-types) for the different types of FCM messages.

In order to see your notifications, you can do either of the following:

- Send a [notification message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) instead of a data message, this means you'll use the `notification` key in place of the `data` key in your `message` payload object like below:

```js
const message = {
    notification: {
      title: "warning",
      body: "A new weather warning has been created!",
    },
    topic: "weather",
};
```

- Display the data message using the [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin as outlined in `firebase_messaging's` [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#application-in-foreground)